# Android 4.2 - Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() behaviour

Tags: android, mobile

I've been developing an android application, before the last update to 4.2, I used

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

which returned me /storage/sdcard0/, but since the update I now get /storage/emulated/0.

I've been reading about the multiuser capabilities on Android 4.2 and I'm guessing that's where the 0 comes from, however, I still don't know how to get to the path I was using before the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your path, so just use it. Do not think it over. Paths changed since 4.2 due to multiuser feature. Android shall deal with that on firmware upgrade so you do not need to bother. Just use it as you did so far and do not worry it changed. If your code somehow depends on old value, then fix your code.

Comment: That being said, one hopes that an app already deployed on a device getting the 4.2 upgrade will have `/storage/emulated/0` mapped to the same spot as where files were on 4.1, for the primary device user.