# android Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL (strURL);
            input = url.openStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/"+pos+".png");
```

and I get this error: 
do not hardcode /sd card/ use environment.getexternalstoragedirectory().getpath() instead
in

```
 OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/"+pos+".png");
```

I have read about that:[Android 4.2 - Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459280/android-4-2-environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-getpath-behaviour)

So the question is what will be final code when I replace it?

Comment: OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+pos+".png");

Comment: Sorry to ask but why did you use +pos+ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sd folder name different in Some phones

In samsung phones, it is named external_sd , and your code will fail.

control+shift+o --> to add imports in eclipse,[see this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

```
"/sdcard/" is replace with "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()" in your code
```

The problem was that you call a file called Environment.java itself, so Eclipse didn't give me the choice to import Environment change that one.

Answer (score 3):

Your revised code should look like

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+pos+".png");
```

You should be careful as not all devices have a `/sdcard/` path.

Devices across the years have changed and this may not always contain a link to the proper external storage directory.